# Map Annotation Adding Image

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Below, I have created an Annotation for my map which works perfectly and shows up with the title and subtitle as it should.

But I wish to add a small image to the left of the annotation but can't figure out what I need to do to the below code to make it work.

```
// Annotation
CLLocationCoordinate2D poseLocation;
poseLocation.latitude = POSE_LATITUDE;
poseLocation.longitude = POSE_LONGITUDE;

Annotation *myAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
myAnnotation.coordinate = poseLocation;
myAnnotation.title = @"Pose Beauty Salon";
myAnnotation.subtitle = @"100, Moneyhaw Road";

[self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
```

Comment: Unrelated but you should do `[[Annotation alloc] init];` instead of just `[Annotation alloc];`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the delegate of your myMapView first and implement the viewForAnnotation delegate method.

There you will return MKAnnotationView instance which has a property leftCalloutAccessoryView:

> The view to display on the left side of the standard callout bubble.
>   The default value of this property is nil. The left callout view is
>   typically used to display information about the annotation or to link
>   to custom information provided by your application. The height of your
>   view should be 32 pixels or less.

In the leftCalloutAccessoryView, you can assign your image there. For example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annotation"];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"];            
        UIImageView *imageView = //initialize your image view here
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView;
    }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    return annotationView;
}
```

PS: Apparently you have asked similar question before here: [Add image to the left of my annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420853/add-image-to-the-left-of-my-annotations). I am not sure you need to post another question. Please try to implement this first.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];

myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagename];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,35.0, 35.0);
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cropRect];
myImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myImageView.image = myImage;
MyPin.leftCalloutAccessoryView =myImageView;
MyPin.highlighted=YES;
MyPin.canShowCallout=YES;
return MyPin;
```

}

It works for me , try this one